# Does the 'no bar' here mean 'bar none'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He was a man who would have made a success of life a century and a
>   half ago when conversation was a passport to good company and
>   inebriety **no bar**.
>
> "I ought to have lived in the eighteen hundreds," he said himself.
>   "What I want is a patron. I should have published my poems by
>   subscription and dedicated them to a nobleman. I long to compose
>   rhymed couplets upon the poodle of a countess. My soul yearns for the
>   love of chamber-maids and the conversation of bishops."
>
> *Of Human Bondage by W. Somerset Maugham*

Does the '**no bar**' here mean '**bar none**'?

Comment: The repeated predicate "was" is understood. "...conversation was a passport...and inebriety *was* no bar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it means '**not a problem**' or '**not a disqualification**'.

A century and a half ago, one *would not be barred* from good company for inebreity.